# Combining element-wise and matrix multiplication with multi-dimensional arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have two multidimensional NumPy arrays, `A` and `B`, with `A.shape = (K, d, N)` and `B.shape = (K, N, d)`. I would like to perform an element-wise operation over axis 0 (`K`), with that operation being matrix multiplication over axes 1 and 2 (`d, N` and `N, d`). So the result should be a multidimensional array `C` with `C.shape = (K, d, d)`, so that `C[k] = np.dot(A[k], B[k])`. A naive implementation would look like this:

```
C = np.vstack([np.dot(A[k], B[k])[np.newaxis, :, :] for k in xrange(K)])
```

but this implementation is *slow*. A slightly faster approach looks like this:

```
C = np.dot(A, B)[:, :, 0, :]
```

which uses the default behaviour of `np.dot` on multidimensional arrays, giving me an array with shape `(K, d, K, d)`. However, this approach computes the required answer `K` times (each of the entries along axis 2 are the same). Asymptotically it will be slower than the first approach, but the overhead is much less. I am also aware of the following approach:

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import matrix_multiply
C = matrix_multiply(A, B)
```

but I am not guaranteed that this function will be available. My question is thus, does NumPy provide a standard way of doing this efficiently? An answer which applies to multidimensional arrays in general would be perfect, but an answer specific to only this case would be great too.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Juh_, the second approach is incorrect. The correct version is:

```
C = np.dot(A, B).diagonal(axis1=0, axis2=2).transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

but the overhead added makes it *slower* than the first approach, even for small matrices. The last approach is winning by a long shot on all my timing tests, for small and large matrices. I'm now strongly considering using this if no better solution crops up, even if that would mean copying the `numpy.core.umath_tests` library (written in C) into my project.

Comment: Have you had a look at `tensordot`?  I'm a bit short on time right now, so I can't give a full example, but it should (I think) do exactly what you want. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html

Comment: I've had a look at `np.tensordot`, but I fear that it won't solve my problem. The issue being that tensordot takes _pairs_ of axes to sum over. The only way in which I could "get rid" of one of the `K`-length axes is by summing over it, which forces me to pair it with the other `K`-length axis. Doing so eliminates both of them, so that my result no longer has a `K`-length axis.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution to your problem is:

```
C = np.sum(A[:,:,:,np.newaxis]*B[:,np.newaxis,:,:],axis=2)
```

However:

1. it is quicker than the vstack approach only if K is much bigger than d and N
2. their might be some memory issue: in the above solution an KxdxNxd array is allocated (i.e. all possible product paires, before summing). Actually I could not test with big K,d and N as I was going out of memory.

btw, note that:

```
C = np.dot(A, B)[:, :, 0, :]
```

does not give the correct result. It got me tricked because I first checked my method by comparing the results to those given by this np.dot command.

Comment: Apologies, you're right. It's actually `np.dot(A, B)[k, :, k, :] == np.dot(A[k], B[k])`. So the answer is a bit more complicated. Something like `np.dot(A, B).diagonal(axis1=0, axis2=2).transpose(2,0,1)` seems to do the trick, but has the same problem as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue in my project. The best I've been able to come up with is, I think it's a little faster (maybe 10%) than using `vstack`:

```
K, d, N = A.shape
C = np.empty((K, d, d))
for k in xrange(K):
    C[k] = np.dot(A[k], B[k])
```

I'd love to see a better solution, I can't quite see how one would use `tensordot` to do this.

Comment: `numpy.core.umath_tests.matrix_multiply` seems to be the perfect solution. It's a pity that it isn't included as a standard NumPy function. See my reply to @Joe's comment on my question for my reasoning behind why `np.tensordot` can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

A very flexible, compact, and fast solution:

```
C = np.einsum('Kab,Kbc->Kac', A, B, optimize=True)
```

Confirmation:

```
import numpy as np
K = 10
d = 5
N = 3
A = np.random.rand(K,d,N)
B = np.random.rand(K,N,d)
C_old = np.dot(A, B).diagonal(axis1=0, axis2=2).transpose(2, 0, 1)
C_new = np.einsum('Kab,Kbc->Kac', A, B)
print(np.max(C_old-C_new))  # should be 0 or a very small number
```

For large multi-dimensional arrays, the optional parameter `optimize=True` can save you a lot of time.
You can learn about *einsum* here:

https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/

https://rockt.github.io/2018/04/30/einsum

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Quote:

> The Einstein summation convention can be used to compute many multi-dimensional, linear algebraic array operations. **einsum** provides a succinct way of representing these. A non-exhaustive list of these operations is:
>
> - Trace of an array, **numpy.trace**.
> - Return a diagonal, **numpy.diag**.
> - Array axis summations, **numpy.sum**.
> - Transpositions and permutations, **numpy.transpose**.
> - Matrix multiplication and dot product, **numpy.matmul** **numpy.dot**.
> - Vector inner and outer products, **numpy.inner** **numpy.outer**.
> - Broadcasting, element-wise and scalar multiplication, **numpy.multiply**.
> - Tensor contractions, **numpy.tensordot**.
> - Chained array operations, in efficient calculation order, **numpy.einsum_path**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
np.matmul(A, B)
```

Look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html.

Should be faster than einsum for big enough `K`.