# Element-wise matrix multiplication in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm making my first real foray into Python and NumPy to do some image processing. I have an image loaded as a 3 dimensional NumPy Array, where axis 0 represents image bands, while axes 1 and 2 represent columns and rows of pixels. From this, I need to take the 3x1 matrix representing each pixel and perform a few operations which result in another 3x1 matrix, which will be used to build a results image.

My first approach (simplified and with random data) looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import random

factor = np.random.rand(3,3)
input = np.random.rand(3,100,100)
results = np.zeros((3,100,100))

for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
        results[:,x,y] = np.dot(factor,input[:,x,y])
```

But this strikes me as inelegant and inefficient. Is there a way to do this in an element-wise fasion, e.g.:

```
results = np.dot(factor,input,ElementWiseOnAxis0)
```

In trying to find a solution to this problem I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325078/combining-element-wise-and-matrix-multiplication-with-multi-dimensional-arrays-i) question, which is obviously quite similar. However, the author was unable to solve the problem to their satisfaction. I am hoping that either something has changed since 2012, or my problem is sufficiently different from theirs to make it more easily solvable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Numpy arrays use element-wise multiplication by default. Check out [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and [numpy.tensordot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html). I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
results = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl',factor,input)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for these data and should be adaptable to similar problems as well, thanks!

Comment: In my case input shape's is: (100, 100, 3). Took me a while to understand it, but might be useful to others. In my case it was:

    results = np.einsum('ij,klj->kli',factor,input)