# Single operation to take the matrix product along only the last two dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

This is probably obvious on reflection, but it's not clear to me right now.

For a pair of numpy arrays of shapes `(K, N, M)` and `(K, M, N)` denoted by `a` and `b` respectively, is there a way to compute the following as a single vectorized operation:

```
import numpy as np
K = 5
N = 2
M = 3
a = np.random.randn(K, N, M)
b = np.random.randn(K, M, N)

output = np.empty((K, N, N))
for each_a, each_b, each_out in zip(a, b, output):
    each_out[:] = each_a.dot(each_b)
```

A simple `a.dot(b)` returns the dot product for every pair of the first axis (so it returns an array of shape `(K, N, K, N)`.

edit: fleshed out the code a bit for those that couldn't understand the question.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but aren't you looking for `a.dot(b)`?

Comment: No, as explained, `a.dot(b)` returns an array that is of shape `(K, N, K, N)` - that is, the dot product for every pair of the first axes. What I want to achieve is described by the code. Is this not clear?

Comment: I only had time for a quick look and the difference between that (and my proposed solution) wasn't clear to me without testing. But it looks like farenorth already has a nice solution for you :)

Comment: @Wolph no probs. I was feeling grumpy about being downvoted :)

Comment: that wasn't me, not sure why anyone would downvote as the question is perfectly fine in my opinion :)

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it wasn't you after your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a similar question a while back: [Element-wise matrix multiplication in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922212/element-wise-matrix-multiplication-in-numpy/25922418#25922418) .

I think what you're looking for is:

```
output = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', a, b)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I played a bit with einsum but end of day brain frazzle stopped a suitable answer :)

Comment: This is a case where the `einsum` ellipsis lets you write an expression that works just as well in 2d as 3d: `'...jk,...kl->...jl'`